# Detecting changes to SSIS Packages

Tags: ssis

Question for the community ...
Is anyone aware of anyway to detect changes to SSIS packages in SQL Server 2012?

To be specific, in our builds we use DTUTIL to deploy the changes to production. But it would be great if we could use something like a trigger to log this change to a database table.

But even a query on a system table somewhere would be useful if we could see when the packages were updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Why not use the Build to log that change instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that rudimentary system table query you're looking for, you can try [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSIS-packages-3b247394) - note that your table names may be different (see the Q&A comment about `sysssispackage(folders)`).  I could envision utilizing the `CreateDate`, `Version` and `PackageSize` fields.

Also, Andy Leonard has been blogging about a new tool he created called SSIS Catalog Compare which may help.

(To stick with the SO spirit, here is the SQL from the above link).

```
-- List all SSIS packages stored in msdb database. 
SELECT PCK.name AS PackageName 
      ,PCK.[description] AS [Description] 
      ,FLD.foldername AS FolderName 
      ,CASE PCK.packagetype 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Default client' 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'I/O Wizard' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'DTS Designer' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Replication' 
            WHEN 5 THEN 'SSIS Designer' 
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Maintenance Plan' 
            ELSE 'Unknown' END AS PackageTye 
      ,LG.name AS OwnerName 
      ,PCK.isencrypted AS IsEncrypted 
      ,PCK.createdate AS CreateDate 
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10), vermajor) 
       + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10), verminor) 
       + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(10), verbuild) AS Version 
      ,PCK.vercomments AS VersionComment 
      ,DATALENGTH(PCK.packagedata) AS PackageSize 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90 AS PCK 
     INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysdtspackagefolders90 AS FLD 
         ON PCK.folderid = FLD.folderid 
     INNER JOIN sys.syslogins AS LG 
         ON PCK.ownersid = LG.sid 
ORDER BY PCK.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I had to modify it as I'm using SQL Server 2012. But hopefully I can get this to work for me. And I'll check out the blog you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I had to modify too: switching `msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90` to `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages` and `msdb.dbo.sysdtspackagefolders90` to `msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the product mention! You can learn more about SSIS Catalog Compare at https://dilmsuite.com/ssis-catalog-compare.